# Node.js How to get the IP address of http server listening on a specific port

Tags: node.js

I've a following very basic code of HTTP server which is listening on port 8000. How to determine the IP address of server, can it be retrieved from the 'server' variable? I am working on an application where I need to automatically send the server Info (ip,port etc..) to redis store.

I'm new to node.js, Thanks for the help

```
var http = require("http");
var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
  response.write("Hello!!!");
  response.end();
});
```

```
server.listen(8000);
console.log("Server is listening....");
```

Answer (score 23):

Use the following:

```
server.address()
```

Which logs something like:

```
{ address: '0.0.0.0', family: 'IPv4', port: 8080 }
```

To log the IP of your server to the console, use:

```
console.log( server.address().address );
```

Comment: This is the correct answer as `address` is a method, not a property

Comment: I just get this: "ReferenceError: server is not defined"

Comment: Actually, the `address()` comes from `net.Server`, which is the super class of `http.Server`.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want the address your server is bound to, you can use `server.address.address` to get the IP address the server is bound to. Similarly, you can use `server.address.port` to get the port number that the server is bound to.

From: http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_server_address.

Comment: Its not working it returns 0.0.0.0 ip address.Any Ideas? {"address":"0.0.0.0","family":"IPv4","port":8000}

Comment: From: http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_listen_port_hostname_backlog_callback. If you don't pass a hostname to bind it it will be default bind to 0.0.0.0. As you're only specifying a port it will bind to 0.0.0.0 by default and the returned object from server.address would be correct.

Comment: See Alistair MacDonald's answer: server.address().address, not server.address.address

Comment: is there any way to get the public ip?

Comment: If there is not set the Ip address then the ip will be set default by Node js. You can set the ip address by these: `server.listen(8888,'127.0.0.1', function(){})`

Answer (score 3):

```
req.connection.remoteAddress
req.connection.remotePort
req.connection.localAddress
req.connection.localPort
```

Comment: please add explanation as your post came in "low quality post" category