# How can I get my interface gateway using NodeJs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, networking

I've built a simple code to show my current network configuration:

```
const getNetInfo = () => {
    let networkInterfaces = os.networkInterfaces();

    let nets = [];
    Object.keys(networkInterfaces).map(name => {
        networkInterfaces[name]?.map(n => {
            if (n.family === "IPv4" && !n.internal) {
                let gateway = "Unknown"; <==== I need a way to get the gateway
                                               from the interface

                nets.push({
                    interface: name,
                    gateway: gateway,
                    ...n
                })
            }
        })
    })

    return nets;
}
```

That works fine, except that id does not bring my gateway address (check the comment in code):

```
[
  {
    interface: 'en1',
    gateway: 'Unknown',
    address: '192.168.0.103',
    netmask: '255.255.255.0',
    family: 'IPv4',
    mac: 'f0:18:98:b2:3f:fb',
    internal: false,
    cidr: '192.168.0.103/24'
  }
]
```

I really need to add gateway info to the interface.... how can I do it?

Comment: you can shell out an os command (eg ipconfig) and parse the response.

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41695391/whats-the-best-way-to-find-default-gateway-ip-in-node-js

Comment: What operating system are you using? On Unix, gateways are not associated with interfaces, they're part of the system-wide routing table.

Comment: I'm using Linux... Will be used on Raspi